# Установить угол вращения для матрицы из boost::qvm

Tags: c++, boost

К примеру у меня есть матрица

```
boost::qvm::mat<float, 3, 3> mat{...};
```

и я устанавилваю для нее угол вращения

```
boost::qvm::rotate_z(mat, angle);
```

Как после этого изменить угол (значения матрицы отвечающие за поворот), чтобы при этом не удалить другие значения, хранящиеся в матрице (скейл, позиция)

Пробовал

```
boost::qvm::set_rotz(mat, angle);
```

но при этом, как раз таки, затираются нужные остальные значения в матрице

Answer (score 0):

Храните матрицы элементарных преобразований отдельно и при модификации одной их них снова все комбинируйте (перемножайте).

Comment: зачем, в таком случае хранить матрицы, а не простые значения?

Comment: Чтобы не тратить время на создание матриц. Если у Вас всё время одни и те же масштабирование и перенос, можно их комбинацию хранить. Но это действительно крохи, и с простыми значениями будет неплохо.